# Comentario/legenda nas linhas da tabela

Tags: html, css

Como posso adicionar um comentário/legenda nas linhas da tabela, semelhante a tag `<abbr>`?

```html
nome | idade | sexo
<br>
<abbr title="comentario/legenda 1">&nbsp; Gui &nbsp;| &nbsp;&nbsp;17 &nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;M</abbr>
<br>
<abbr title="comentario/legenda 2">&nbsp;&nbsp; Jô &nbsp;&nbsp;| &nbsp;&nbsp;17 &nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;M</abbr>
```

Comment: Guilherme, mas já esta adicionando o comentário/legenda, por que precisa de algo semelhante ao do que está fazendo ?

Comment: porque as minhas tabelas não são com texto, espaços e `<br>`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## EDIT:

Relendo a pergunta entendi que vc quer o efeito apenas na linha da tabela `<tr>`. Então seguem duas formas de fazer seguindo a ideia da resposta já dada.

```css
tr {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid salmon;
}
tr:first-of-type:hover::after {
    content: attr(data-text);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    background-color: powderblue;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid salmon
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr data-text="descrição n# 1">
        <td >TR</td>
        <td>com hover::after</td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="descrição n# 2">
        <td>TR</td>
        <td>com title=""</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

Segue uma solução simples usando *pseudo-elemento* e um atributo customizado no `content`

```css
td {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid salmon;
}
td:hover::after {
    content: attr(data-text);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    top: 115%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: powderblue;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td data-text="descrição n# 1">item 1</td>
        <td data-text="descrição n# 2">item 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-text="descrição n# 3">item 3</td>
        <td data-text="descrição n# 4">item 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

Agora, tem alguns elementos que aceita o atributo `title=""` na tag, e eles funcionam de forma semelhante ao `<abbr>` como por exemplo a tag `<a>` e a `<p>`

```html
<a href="#" title="meu link">deixe o mouse</a>
<p title="tag p">isso é um P</p>
```

Vc pode fazer o mesmo na tabela, mas não vai conseguir fazer funcionar na TR apenas nas TD

```css
table {border: 1px solid black}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr title="teste TR 1">
        <td title="teste 1" data-text="descrição n# 1">item 1</td>
        <td title="teste 2" data-text="descrição n# 2">item 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="teste TR 1">
        <td title="teste 3" data-text="descrição n# 3">item 3</td>
        <td title="teste 4" data-text="descrição n# 4">item 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**OBS:** Considerações sobre acessibilidade e o atributo `title`

> O uso do atributo title é altamente problemático para:

- Pessoas que usam dispositivos somente de toque
- Pessoas navegando com teclados
- Pessoas que navegam com o auxílio de tecnologia assistiva, como leitores de tela ou lupas
- Pessoas com deficiências no controle motor
- Pessoas com preocupações cognitivas

*Fonte:* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title

Comment: Eu sabia que a tag `<img>` também tinha, o link não sabia. As tags de tabela aceitam o atributo `title`?

Comment: Funciona porém isso aplica a funcionalidade numa célula, também funciona para aplicar numa linha?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam editei a minha resposta com os seus questionamentos. Sobre a `title` na TR acredito que só seja possível com CSS ou JS

Comment: Poderia adicionar um exemplo (com CSS e/ou JS)?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam com JS eu não sei pq não entendo muito. Com CSS fiz um teste e é complicado de fazer o :hover na TR, pois a TD meio que ocupa o espaço inteiro da "celula". O elemento `<table>` tem várias particularidades...

Comment: Tirando o title das TDs não funciona?

Comment: @dvd tirando o title das TD o title das TR funcionam sim!

Comment: Então? Não era esse o problema, que aparecesse apenas o title das TRs?

Comment: @dvd eu achei que ele queria nos dois ao mesmo tempo TD e TR, ai tinha complicado rss, viajei.... Mas se é só na TR facilita tanto pra fazer com title quanto com CSS e ::after por exemplo... ou JS tb se quiser

Comment: @dvd editei a minha resposta colocando só nas TR valeu o toque!